# Document contour detection using opencv

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing, android-camera, yuv

I am trying to render the largest contour on the preview frame of the camera. Here is my code:

```
    @Override
    public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        previewSize = cameraConfigUtil.cameraInstance.getParameters().getPreviewSize();
        Mat srcMat = new Mat(previewSize.height, previewSize.width, CvType.CV_8UC3);
        srcMat.put(0, 0, data);
        rect = ImageCorrection.getLargestContour(data, previewSize.height, previewSize.width);
        android.graphics.Rect rectangle = new android.graphics.Rect();
        rectangle.left = rect.x;
        rectangle.top = rect.y;
        rectangle.right = rect.x + rect.width;
        rectangle.bottom = rect.y + rect.height;
        mOverlay.clear();
        BarcodeGraphic graphic = new BarcodeGraphic(mOverlay);
        mOverlay.add(graphic);
        graphic.updateItem(rectangle);
        Imgproc.rectangle(srcMat, new Point(rect.x, rect.y), new Point(rect.x + rect.width, rect.y + rect.height), new Scalar(255, 0, 0, 255), 3);
        Utils.matToBitmap(srcMat, bitmap);
    }
```

It detects the contour but when I add it to the overlay the box is not placed on the document and the bounding rectangle looks smaller. I am using the raw data from the preview frame. What am I missing ? Basically the largest contour detected is not relative to the actual preview size.

```
 public static Rect getLargestContour(byte[] data, int height, int width) {
        Mat srcMat = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC3);
        srcMat.put(0, 0, data);
        Mat imgSource = new Mat(srcMat.size(), CvType.CV_8UC1);
        Imgproc.cvtColor(srcMat, imgSource, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY, 4);
        Imgproc.GaussianBlur(imgSource, imgSource, new org.opencv.core.Size(5, 5), 0);

        Imgproc.Canny(imgSource, imgSource, 50, 50);

        List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<>();
        Imgproc.findContours(imgSource, contours, new Mat(), Imgproc.RETR_LIST, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
        Imgproc.cvtColor(imgSource, srcMat, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2RGB, 4);

        double maxArea = -1;
        Log.d("size", Integer.toString(contours.size()));
        MatOfPoint temp_contour;
        MatOfPoint2f approxCurve = new MatOfPoint2f();

        for (MatOfPoint contour : contours) {
            double contourarea = Imgproc.contourArea(contour);
            if (contourarea > 0
                    && contourarea > maxArea) {
                //check if this contour is a square
                MatOfPoint2f new_mat = new MatOfPoint2f(contour.toArray());
                int contourSize = (int) contour.total();
                MatOfPoint2f approxCurve_temp = new MatOfPoint2f();
                Imgproc.approxPolyDP(new_mat, approxCurve_temp, contourSize * 0.05, true);
                if (approxCurve_temp.total() == 4) {
                    maxArea = contourarea;
                    approxCurve = approxCurve_temp;
                }
            }
        }

        MatOfPoint points = new MatOfPoint(approxCurve.toArray());

        return Imgproc.boundingRect(points);
    }
```

[image]

This is the image size that opencv is considering.

[image]

Comment: Please add some images for those with bad imaginationen

Comment: I have attached an image

Comment: I am not converting the YUV format to RGB is that the reason ?

Comment: So your byte[] data is YUV and then you convert rgb to gray? Is the detected contour right? (e.g. did you draw the contour to check the result?).Maybe you took the wrong one. Why 4 channels in cvtColor?

Comment: The contours are right but smaller in relation to the actual image eizev. How many cvtColor channels should I have. I am new to openCV

Comment: I meant if the original contour in your grayscale image is right, not the one in the overlay. If you convert to rgb you need 3 channels, if you just say `cvtColor(src,dst,CV_GRAY2BGR)`  opencv choose the channels accordingly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123506/discussion-between-rohit-ramkumar-and-pschn).

Comment: updated another image

Answer (score 0):

So finally found the issue :

```
 Mat srcMat = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC3);
 srcMat.put(0, 0, data);
```

I am putting data which is of YUV type in a Mat that is CV_8U3. It should be CV_8U1.

```
 Mat srcMat = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC1);
 srcMat.put(0, 0, data);
```

and we don't need to convert it to GRAYSCALE:

```
 Mat imgSource = new Mat(srcMat.size(), CvType.CV_8UC1);
 Imgproc.cvtColor(srcMat, imgSource, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY, 4);
```